# Posting data to a third party.... (what does the third party have to do on their end to receive my data?)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm just trying to understand how this works... so hopefully this doesn't come across as a dumb question.

But lets say I have a html/PHP form on my site, which POSTS the data to a third party system... what does the third party have to do on their end to receive my data?

Lets say my form looks like this:

```
<form id="userdata" method="post" action="https://thirdparty.com/receive_data.php">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="user_name">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="user_email">
    <label>Phone</label>
    <input type="text" name="user_phone">
    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea rows="20" cols="50" name="user_message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In this example, I'm posting data to https://thirdparty.com/receive_data.php
So I assume the third party then has code inside receive_data.php which tells the system how to grab my data and send it to their database. Does the code of the third party look similar to the code I'd be using when I try to store my OWN form's data to my own database? Do they use extra code to allow third party data to go into their database. Can someone explain this to me and maybe give me a code example so I can understand this better.

Comment: If there isn't any specific security restrictions (like csrf, oauth, tokens, basic/digest auth etc), then there doesn't need to be anything different from when you store it yourself. It's simply a POST request.

Comment: Normally third parties tell *you* how to provide the data and it's up to you to send it in the way they expect.

Comment: ok... so let's say I have a form on my site which stores my form's data in my own database... and my form posts to "send_data.php".... Does that mean someone else can send data from their website to my database by just having action="http://mydomain/send_data.php" in their form tag? So that file would store the data regardless of whether it comes from my own domain/form or theirs?

Comment: Yes, anyone can post data to your script, if you don't have any protection against it, like: [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend you to use CURL.

Curl extension has a lot of options that you can set, for example the connection time out. You can also add post variables or access the site with a specific referer. It also give response that sending url/server working fine or not.

There are n number of feature which you can see in below link:
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/comparison-table.html

Everything you need to know about it (and most other extensions) can be found in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest use cURL to send some data to other site.

```
$url = "https://thirdparty.com/receive_data.php";
$data = $_POST; // or something else, it depends on you what should be send

$ch = curl_init ($url );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec ($ch); //Third part response, for example in JSON format
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain WHY he should use cURL, and how this relates to his actual question?